# Load TTNavigator when needed,Show another viewController without persisting it in Navigator

Tags: ios, uikit, three20

I am making an application in which user needs to login/sign up, if
the application opens for the first time or there are no default login
info available. This login/signup view is regular UIViewController
View.
Now, I have a MainMenu View which is TTLauncherView which would be
shows to the user
 - if user successfully login/(signup and login)
 - if there are already saved info in userdefaults and the saved
credentials are authenticated by the server
So the login/signup page would be visible to user only when there are
no userdefaults saved.
I have implemented both (login.signup page separately and a functional
launcherview which is the MainMenu view), but am not able to redirect
user after successful login, as it initiates the TTNavigator and I
don't want to persist the login page in the Navigator's page
heirarchy.
After alot of search I figures, that I can change the Key Window and
implement both on separate windows and after a successful login make
the other window key-window and resign the previous one. But I am not
sure how to do it and is this the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on Three20 google group, so wanted to share if anyone's interested 
There are 2 ways to do it,

1. After login was successful, clear the memory of all the views ever persisted (in my case just 1) using.

   ```
   [navigator removeAllViewControllers];
   ```
2. Present the login screen as ModalViewController and after successful login, dismiss the ModalViewController, which deallocs the view and is not persisited.

to present the Login as ModalViewController:

```
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:
@"tt://account"] applyTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight]
applyAnimated:YES] ];
```

to dismiss the view controller:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```